# Google Maps API change view when options menu button was pressed?

Tags: android, google-maps

Im trying to make the view change from traffic to satelite when a button in my options menu is pressed but its not working.. Here is my code:
**Here is my onCrete**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Adding features for the map
    mainMap = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mvMain);
    mainMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    //THESE I WILL USE!!!
    //mainMap.setSatellite(true);
    mainMap.setTraffic(true);
    mapViewControll = true;
    mapController = mainMap.getController();
}
```

**here is my onoptionItemSelected**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){

    //Change View
    case R.id.changeView:
        if(mapViewControll = false){
        mainMap.setSatellite(true);
        }

        else{
            mainMap.setTraffic(true);
        }
        break;

    //Help
    case R.id.help:
        break;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I did set the mapViewControll boolean to true at the top of the code.. What can be a problem here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to put mainMap.setTraffic(false); and vice versa in the onoptionItemSelected method

Answer (score 0):

Try calling invalidate() method on map view at end.

Comment: Tried that and its still not happening anything.